# Payment provider that works in South Africa

Tags: web-development, payments, ecommerce, shopping-cart

I am implimenting nopCommerce and need to accept credit cards, has anyone had any experience with a payment gateway that works in South Africa?

I had a look at Paypal but they don't support ZAR as a currency yet. The other payment provider that I was looking at is Two Checkout.

Comment: Are you looking for a provider that accepts ZAR *as well* or would one accepting ZAR *only* be sufficient? Would you be able/willing to hold/use a merchant bank account with a South African bank for this purpose?

Comment: @user1970 2checkout has been around in business for a really long time, I used them ages ago and had no complaints. I would definitely try them again if I needed an [international payment gateway](https://www.google.com/search?q=international+payment+gateways).

Answer (score 1):

You can also give www.moneybookers.com a try. They are based in Europe and are a competitor of PayPal. They do support ZAR for sure: http://www.moneybookers.com/app/help.pl?s=fees
They are pretty decent, I've been having a personal account with them for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

One of our clients is an Australian company that accepts payments in South Africa in ZAR. The use a combination of http://www.securepay.com.au/ combined with a merchant account from the National Australia Bank that supports multi-currency.

You will have to do something similar. Most payment gateways will accept payments in the form of whatever currency you merchant accounts support.

**However** if I remember correctly, collecting payment in ZAR was a *huge* headache for them because of the regulations in South Africa because of the massive abuse of credit cards in general.

I'm fairly sure they had to get a bank account open in South Africa, which involved them actually having to go there in person and spend a week there signing paperwork and having background checks done. So unless you're actually in South Africa this could be more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

You can give [www.gogopay.com](http://www.gogopay.com) a try. They are based in Europe and accepts major credits cards with transaction fee around 1.5% to 2.6%. Their payout days are 7,14 or 28 days. Check their website.